# Apache Spark and Remote Method Invocation

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-spark, rmi

I am trying to understand how Apache Spark works behind the scenes. After coding a little in Spark I am pretty quite sure that it implements the `RDD` as RMI *Remote objects*, doesn't it?

In this way, it can modify them inside transformation, such as `map`s, `flatMap`s, and so on. Object that are not part of an `RDD` are simply serialized and sent to a worker during execution.

In the example below, `lines` and `tokens`will be treated as *remote objects*, while the string `toFind` will be simply serialized and copied to the workers.

```
val lines: RDD[String] = sc.textFile("large_file.txt")
val toFind = "Some cool string"
val tokens = 
  lines.flatMap(_ split " ")
       .filter(_.contains(toFind))
```

Am I wrong? I googled a little but I've not found any reference to how Spark `RDD` are internally implemented.

Comment: You can check the source code [Scala's RDD](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala).

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto, you're right. But the `RDD.scala` file has more than 1800 sloc :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Spark serializes closures to perform remote method invocation.

Comment: I've asked directly to Roland Kuhn if Spark or Akka uses directly RMI and he answer me: "None of the proper reactive solutions use RMI, that technique is obsolete (search for the difference between transparent remoting and location transparency). In particular Spark does not perform remote calls in the way you think, that would slow it down by orders of magnitude. Instead it serializes the code and sends that to the worker nodes.". This is fundamentally what you've answered.